# Javascript-split() not working when there are repeated chars in a string

Tags: javascript

Not sure how valid is this approach, but I'm unable to split the string into 2 when there are repeated characters.

```
 var match = 's';
 var str = "message";
 var res = str.split(match, 2);
```

For instance i tried to use split() on the string "message", it results into:

```
me,""
```

So i did this:

```
 res = str.split(match, 3);
```

so now it resulted into:

```
me,,age
```

but as you can see im still missing the second 's' in the "message" string. what im trying to get is I'm passing a matched character (in above case var match which is dynamically generated) to the split() and splitting into 2. I was hoping to get something this:

```
res = me,,sage
```

is that possible using split() or is there a better method to achieve this?

P.S: in fiddle i've given another string eg: (string = "shadow") which works fine.
Fails only when there are repeated letters in the string!

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ukeeq656/

EDIT::::::::::::

Thanks everyone for helping me out on this...and so sorry for last min update on the input, i just realized that `var match;` could be a word too, as in `var match = 'force';` and not just `var match ='s';` where the string is "forceProduct", so when my match is more than just a letter, this approach works: `str.split(match, 2);`, but `str.indexOf(match);` doesnt obviously... could there be an approach to split: "","Product". My extreme apologies for not mentioning this earlier.any help on this would be appreciated!!

eg fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ukeeq656/3/

Comment: So you are happing to call something on "message" and get an array with 2 elements, one is "me" and the other is "sage"?

Comment: what is the desired output? [ 'me', 'age']?

Comment: @kcdragon: yes right~

Comment: @ bryanmac: ideally the first part would be: 'me' and the second part would be 'sage', im getting 'me','age' instead..

Comment: Please describe the precise behavior you are looking for. If the input contains a single "s", then you want to split on that, but not split on immediately following "s" characters? Or on any additional "s' characters anywhere in the string? What if there are three "s" characters in a row?

Comment: `res = me,,sage` is 3 parts,  right? do you want `res = "me", "sage"` instead so it is *splitted into 2* ?

Comment: @torazaburo: yes if the input is 's', I'd like to split on the first 's' found in the string, similarly if input is 'l' and the string is "hello", it will split on the first 'l' found in the string, similarly if there are more then 3 repeated letters, eg: disabledDoubled, i'd ideally split on the first 'd' something like(, isabledDoubled)

Comment: @Frederik.L: i'd definitely like to have 2 parts as long it takes care of multiple repeated letters in a string: eg( string = "onclickCustom" and  match =''c"), it will be something like: ("'',"nclickCustom")

Comment: I don't understand your second example involving "disabledDoubled". Why would this not split into `[, 'isabled', 'oubled']`?

Comment: @all: Thanks for all the help: have updated the quest a little bit..sorry for the  last min change!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think split() is the correct way to do this.

Please see below:

```
var match = 's';
var str = "message";
var index = str.indexOf(match);
var res =[];
res[0] = str.substring(0, index);
res[1] = " ";
res[2] = str.substring(index + 1);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your end goal is but I think this gets you what you want.

```
var match = 's';
var str = "message";
var index = str.indexOf(match);
var res = str.substring(0, index) + ',' + str.substring(index + 1);
alert(res); // me,sage
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function to do this;

```
function newSplit(str, match) {
  var num = str.indexOf(match);
  var res = [];
  res.push(str.substring(0, num));
  //res.push(str.substring(num + 1, str.length)); // this line has been modified
  res.push(str.substring(num + match.length, str.length));
  return res;
}
var match = 'force';
var str = 'forceProduct';
console.log(newSplit(str, match));
```

This is what you want?